# Нужно ли очищать _variant_t перед повторным присвоением?

Tags: c++, c, база-данных, ado

Получаю данные из рекодсета ADO.

```
_variant_t val;

val = rs->Fields->GetItem("fld1")->Value;
// do smth with val
val.Clear(); // ???

val = rs->Fields->GetItem("fld2")->Value;
// do smth with val
val.Clear();
```

Вопрос. Нужно ли вызывать `val.Clear()` перед `val = rs->Fields->GetItem("fld2")->Value` чтобы не было утечек всяких?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, переменную типа `_variant_t` перед повторным присвоением очищать не нужно, ибо согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/variant-t-operator-equal?view=msvc-160) его оператор присваивания очищает любое существующее значение и лишь потом копирует новое значение в объект.